# showing the name of the hard disk devices using grep

Tags: linux, terminal, grep

Why does this command:

```
[jalal@galapagos-20] (42)$ dmesg | egrep '(s|h)d[a-z]'
```

Shows the following? Can you please show step by step?

```
ACPI: SSDT 00000000d8ffbbd8 03528 (v01 SaSsdt  SaSsdt  00003000 INTL 20091112)
NMI watchdog enabled, takes one hw-pmu counter.
sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] 500118192 512-byte logical blocks: (256 GB/238 GiB)
sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] 4096-byte physical blocks
sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Write Protect is off
sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Mode Sense: 00 3a 00 00
sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Write cache: enabled, read cache: enabled, doesn't support DPO or FUA
 sda: sda1 sda2 sda3 sda4 sda5 sda6 sda7
sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Attached SCSI disk
EXT4-fs (sda3): mounted filesystem with ordered data mode. Opts: 
dracut: Mounted root filesystem /dev/sda3
snd_hda_intel 0000:00:03.0: PCI INT A -> GSI 16 (level, low) -> IRQ 16
snd_hda_intel 0000:00:03.0: irq 33 for MSI/MSI-X
snd_hda_intel 0000:00:03.0: setting latency timer to 64
snd_hda_intel 0000:00:1b.0: PCI INT A -> GSI 22 (level, low) -> IRQ 22
snd_hda_intel 0000:00:1b.0: irq 34 for MSI/MSI-X
snd_hda_intel 0000:00:1b.0: setting latency timer to 64
sound hdaudioC1D2: autoconfig for ALC3220: line_outs=1 (0x1b/0x0/0x0/0x0/0x0) type:line
sound hdaudioC1D2:    speaker_outs=1 (0x14/0x0/0x0/0x0/0x0)
sound hdaudioC1D2:    hp_outs=1 (0x15/0x0/0x0/0x0/0x0)
sound hdaudioC1D2:    mono: mono_out=0x0
sound hdaudioC1D2:    inputs:
sound hdaudioC1D2:      Front Mic=0x1a
sound hdaudioC1D2:      Rear Mic=0x18
EXT4-fs (sda1): mounted filesystem with ordered data mode. Opts: 
EXT4-fs (sda7): mounted filesystem with ordered data mode. Opts: 
EXT4-fs (sda4): mounted filesystem with ordered data mode. Opts: 
EXT4-fs (sda6): mounted filesystem with ordered data mode. Opts: 
EXT4-fs (sda5): mounted filesystem with ordered data mode. Opts: 
Adding 67108860k swap on /dev/sda2.  Priority:-1 extents:1 across:67108860k SS
snd_hda_intel 0000:00:1b.0: IRQ timing workaround is activated for card #1. Suggest a bigger bdl_pos_adj.
```

Comment: What is the real question here? Do you know what dmesg does? Do you understand pipes in Unix? Do you know what egrep does? Do you know what is a regular expression? Do you expect the command to output anything else?

Comment: the combination I guess mostly understanding the regex

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The command `dmesg` dumps the kernel log buffer to stdout.  This output consists of a bunch of log messages, each on a separate line.

That output is piped to the command `egrep` with the option `(s|h)d[a-z]`.  `egrep` checks its stdin (the output of dmesg) one line at a time for a match against the regular expression `(s|h)d[a-z]`.  This regular expression will match a series of characters where:

- The first character is s or h
- The second character is d
- The third character is in the ASCII range (inclusive) between a and z (the lowercase letters a to z).

egrep prints to stdout any lines which match the supplied regular expression.

Answer (score 1):

The egrep command is using the regular expression `(s|h)d[a-z]` for filtering lines containing the sequences `hda` to `hdz` and `sda` to `sdz` on the output of dmesg - traditional names for disk devices in Linux.

This regular expression could be switched to `[sh]d[a-z]`, which has the same effect but you may find easier to understand.

There are several false positives if you are looking for disks, like the lines containing "hdaudio".